# How to not lose the initialized Validators after using setValidators Dynamically in Angular?

Tags: angular, dynamic, angular-reactive-forms, customvalidator, form-control

I have a parent component Where I create a FormControl Array and initialize it with Validations.required Validator.

In Child Component I am adding a Dynamic Validator based on input from parent (true/false) but adding that Validator will remove 'required' from the Control.

How can I keep the initialized and later added Validators in the Form Control?

Comment: you can not, but you can create a custom validator that take account the value of the two controls

Comment: I am not sure why everyone is denying it as the Accepted Answer worked for me

Comment: The acepted response add a new validator, but you can not remove it if the condition change. I understand you want to add/remove the "required" if you check/uncheck a input type check in your form

Comment: Yea, that's a good point. Thanks, I know the accepted solution works only if you want to add Validators which covers my scenario for now but I will keep this in mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SetValidators will overwrite the validators with whatever you set. What you need to do is append additional validators keeping the current ones intact. See code below to do this.

```
    this.<<formControl>>.setValidators([
        this.newValidator(),
        this.<<formControl>>.validator
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per official document

> Sets the synchronous validators that are active on this control. **Calling this overwrites any existing sync validators.**

So It is important to keep in mind that by using this method you will overwrite your existing validators so you will need to include all the validators you need/want for the control that you are resetting.

Official Document: https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setValidators

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to know how to include all the Validators. Since the one set during Initialization will be lost. Above solution worked